# Delauny triangulation for stls

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, openfoam, stl-format

i want to triangulate a 3D Array of points to create stls for openFoam. The body i want to create is a plate with corrugations alongside its length typically found in plate heat exchangers. For the creation of the stl i use numpy stl and for the triangulation i use delauny triangulation from scipy. The triangulation itself creates a nice stl, however it doesn't account for the edges and therefore i can't create the corrugations.

```
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
import stl
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot
import math as math
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

b = 0.5 # width plate
d = 0.05 # width corrugation
a = 60 # angle corrugation
t_1 = -0.01 # depth corrugation


########################## UPPER PLATE WITH CORRUGATION #######################

# vertices of the corrugation as start and reference
vertices_upperPlate= np.array([\
    [0, 0, 0],
    [-b/2, -((b/2)/np.tan((a/180)*np.pi)),0],
    [b/2, -((b/2)/np.tan((a/180)*np.pi)),0],
    [0,d,0], 
    [-b/2, -((b/2)/np.tan((a/180)*np.pi))+d,0],
    [b/2, -((b/2)/np.tan((a/180)*np.pi))+d,0]])
    
# Copy the definitions with z offset (t_1)
vertices_upperPlateCorrugation = np.copy(vertices_upperPlate)    
vertices_upperPlateCorrugation[:,2] = vertices_upperPlateCorrugation[:,2] + t_1

vertices_upperPlate = np.vstack((vertices_upperPlate, vertices_upperPlateCorrugation))

faces_upperPlate = np.array([\
    [0,1,6],
    [6,1,7],
    [0,2,6],
    [6,2,8],
    [3,4,9],
    [9,4,10],
    [3,5,9],
    [9,5,11],
    [6,7,9],
    [6,9,8],
    [9,7,10],
    [9,8,11]])
    

# tri = Delaunay(vertices_upperPlate)
# faces_upperPlate = tri.convex_hull

# Create the mesh
upperPlate = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(faces_upperPlate.shape[0], dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))
for i, f in enumerate(faces_upperPlate):
    for j in range(3):
        upperPlate.vectors[i][j] = vertices_upperPlate[f[j],:]


# Create a new plot
figure = pyplot.figure()
axes = mplot3d.Axes3D(figure)

# Load the STL files and add the vectors to the plot
your_mesh = upperPlate
axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(your_mesh.vectors))

# Auto scale to the mesh size
scale = your_mesh.points.flatten()
axes.auto_scale_xyz(scale, scale, scale)

# Show the plot to the screen
pyplot.show()

upperPlate.save('toOpenfoam/upperPlate.stl', mode=stl.Mode.ASCII)
```

This does create following desired single corrugation:[sorry i am not allowed to attach pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21x3f.png)

If i change the triangulation from manual to delauny i get following:

[triangulation with delauny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbxSr.png)

My main question comes down to this:
Can i somehow alter the triangulation to account for changes in dimensions within a plane? If so, i could triangulate over the plane and have the corrugation also covered. It would be really helpful as this triangulation doesn't raise any error within openFoams meshing tool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A Delaunay triangulation is a type of triangulation that reduces the number of narrow triangles and does not depend on vertex ordering. You can create a Delaunay triangulation with the delaunay and delaunay functions, or create a delaunayTriangulation object that has object functions for computing geometric quantities. You can visualize the triangulation and work with STL files to write triangulation data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).